# SAP JAVA VDM split $filter in input

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I've create a project VDM java.In Query response i would like to split the input filters is it possible?

public class ControStatus {

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Query(serviceName = "CatalogService", entity = "ControStatus")
public QueryResponse getEntity(QueryRequest queryRequest) {

    DefaultZSCPSCPDISRVService ControlStatus = new DefaultZSCPSCPDISRVService();


        FilterExpression filtriFrontEnd = FilterExpressionConverter.convertTo(queryRequest.getQueryExpression());
        

        log.error("Filtri" + filtriFrontEnd.toString());

}
```

}

When they call srv passing some filters eg. .... / CatalogService / ControStatus? $ Filter = Bukrs eq "XXXX" and Werks eq "XXXX".  I can read them with `queryRequest.getQueryExpression()`, in the form of filter.Expression. There is a way to turn the answer into a json and read the individual values.Es. What value did they pass for bukrs or werks?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you please expand the question to explain what you are trying to achieve? What does "splitting the input filters" mean? Can you give an example to explain this?

Comment: When they call srv passing some filters eg. .... / CatalogService / ControStatus? $ Filter = Bukrs eq "XXXX" and Werks eq "XXXX".  I can read them with queryRequest.getQueryExpression (), in the form of filter.Expression. There is a way to turn the answer into a json and read the individual values. Eg what value did they pass for bukrs or werks?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way how to extract the information from the type `FilterExpression`. This is API coming from the CAP / SAP Service SDK library. You can find their official [documentation here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/related-projects/cloud-application-model/). My suggestion would be to ask the authors of this library. The tag `sap-cloud-sdk` refers to a different API, the [SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/). Let me know if you need help for establishing contact.

I know that the class is regularly used with `Object#toString` method for constructing a query string. In a similar fashion you could extract the field values via regex:

```java
FilterExpression filtriFrontEnd;

String input = filtriFrontEnd.toString()

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(and |or |)?(\\w+) (eq|ne|gt) ('[^']*?'|[\\d]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    // matcher.group(2)
    // matcher.group(3)
    // matcher.group(4)
}
```

Example:

```java
String input = "$filter=Bukrs eq 'XXXX' and (Werks eq 'XXXX' or (Age gt 1))";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(and |or |)?(\\w+) (eq|ne|gt) ('[^']*?'|[\\d]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("field: %s, operation: %s, value: %s%n", matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3), matcher.group(4));
}

---

field: Bukrs, operation: eq, value: 'XXXX'
field: Werks, operation: eq, value: 'XXXX'
field: Age, operation: gt, value: 1
```

The problem is: you wouldn't know whether the filters are part of a conjunction or disjunction, parentheses are also not considered. In addition you should consider other operations than `eq`/`ne`/`gt` as well.